# How to group by range of values in Java 8 using streams

Tags: java, java-8

Here is a sample scenario:

Imagine we have employee records like:

```
name, age, salary (in 1000 dollars)
   a,  20,     50
   b,  22,     53
   c,  34,     79
```

and so on. The goal is to calculate the average salary of different age groups (for instance between 21 and 30 and 31 to 40 and so on).

I want to do this using `stream` and I just cant get my head around how I need to use `groupingBy` to get this done. I am thinking maybe I need to define some sort of tuple age range. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The below code should give you what you are looking for. The key is "Collectors" class which support grouping.

```
Map<Double,Integer> ageGroup= employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e->Math.ceil(e.age/10.0),Collectors.summingInt(e->e.salary)));
```

The illustration assuming the salary is integer but easy to switch to double

The complete program looks like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employees.add(new Employee("a",20,100));
    employees.add(new Employee("a",21,100));
    employees.add(new Employee("a",35,100));
    employees.add(new Employee("a",32,100));


    Map<Double,Integer> ageGroup= employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e->Math.ceil(e.age/10.0),Collectors.summingInt(e->e.salary)));
    System.out.println(ageGroup);
}

public static class Employee {
    public Employee(String name, int age, int salary) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public int salary;

}
```

The output is

```
{4.0=200, 2.0=100, 3.0=100}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you could define an `AgeGroup` interface or even an `enum` like this (assuming `Employee` definition):

```
enum AgeGroup {
    TWENTIES,
    THIRTIES,
    FORTIES,
    FIFTIES;
    .....
}
Function<Employee, AgeGroup> employee2Group = e -> {
    if(e.age >= 20 && e.getAge() < 30)
        return AgeGroup.TWENTIES;
    ....
    return null;
};

Map<AgeGroup, Double> avgByAgeGroup = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(employee2Group, Collectors.averagingInt(Employee::getSalary)));

avgByAgeGroup.get(AgeGroup.TWENTIES)
```