# Using group by in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Set<CarRange>` and a `List<Car>` as the input of a method. I need to group similar cars and return something like a `Map<CarRange, List<Car>>`. How can I achieve this using java 8 streams?

```
class CarRange {
int startId;
int endId;
}

class Car {
int carId;   
}
```

So if carId lies in between startId and endId it belongs to that `CarRange` object. startId and endId will be unique for each element in `Set<CarRange>`. Hope it makes little more clear.

Comment: Does each Car holds its CarType? If yes why do you need `Set<CarType>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by range of values in Java 8 using streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536295/how-to-group-by-range-of-values-in-java-8-using-streams)

Comment: Could we make that a `SortedSet<CarRange>` sorted by `startId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly I wouldn't do it with streams, this is not actually a 'group by' operation in the sense meant by the streams API so the 'groupBy' collector just won't do what you obviously want. The below more or less does what you want but it's revolting code:

```
    Map<CarRange,List<Car>> map = 
            ranges.stream()
                .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                        range -> range, 
                        range -> cars.stream()
                            .filter(car -> range.carInRange(car))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    )
                );
```

Obviously I added the 'carInRange' method to your CarRange class to avoid making the example even messier than it already is.

Comment: You could make it a ‘group by’ if you had a method for finding the range from the car.

Answer (score 1):

I know you’re happy with Jonathan Essex’ answer, and I am not trying to persuade you to anything else. I was just provoked by the statement “this is not actually a 'group by' operation in the sense meant by the streams API” and wanted to prove you can regard it as such if you want:

```
    CarRange misc = new CarRange(); // for any cars that don’t belong in any other range
    Map<CarRange, List<Car>> map = cars.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> 
                ranges.stream()
                    .filter(r -> r.carInRange(c))
                    .reduce((r1, r2) -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Overlapping ranges " + r1 + " and " + r2); })
                    .orElse(misc)
    ));
    System.out.println("Cars without range? " + map.get(misc));
```

Like Jonathan I am assuming that `CarRange` has a `carInRange` method. My code is about the same size. A possible advantage is it will catch if a car belongs in two ranges, and it’s easy to check if a car belongs in no range at all; I do the latter in the last line. Both snippets are probably equally inefficient, mine perhaps the most inefficient; the group by approach could be optimized if there was a faster way to find the range for a given car. Which we could invent if needed.

Comment: Not sure this is that different in principal as it's still a nested iteration (we are calling 'stream()' on both the cars collection and the ranges collection). My statement about the intent of the 'groupBy' streams API was based on the idea that 'groupBy' is really intended to work on some property intrinsic to the objects being streamed, so that the grouping operation can be performed without the double iteration. I agree, without qualification the statement was provocative. Nice use of 'reduce' to flag the overlapping ranges, that's cool as heck. But I think mine is easier to grok.