# Java streams groupingBy with condition

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

How to group a list by a range of possible values?
If I have a class Foo

```
class Foo{
   int value;
}
```

and a list of foos `List<Foo>` list then

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getValue));
```

will collect my foos which have same value into one group. But I want to group a range of values into one group. For example

```
values < 5 in group "A"
values > 5 && < 25 in group "B"
values >= 25  in group "C"
```

Or another example: Asume I have a list of Integer:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(2,3,4,9,11,17,28,29,32);
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            classifier, 
            Collectors.toList()));
```

I have tried to put something like to classifier

```
 i < 5 ? "A": i >= 5 && i < 25 ? "B" : "C";
```

which gives compilation error. How to do it?

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i < 5 ? "A" : i < 25 ? "B" : "C")` works fine for me, can you show where the compilation error occurs? -> Did you forget to use a lambda?

Comment: @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks My mistake. I have forgotten to put `i ->`. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group by range of values in Java 8 using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536295/how-to-group-by-range-of-values-in-java-8-using-streams)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `Foo::getValue`, provide a function that give the group it belong to:

```
public class B {
    public static String group(int integer) {
        if (i < 5) {
             return "A";
        } else if (i < 25) {
            return "B";
        }
        return "C";
    }
}
```

Then:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(B::group));
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in your classifier you have it return the value.

This should work for your example above:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2,3,4,9,11,17,28,29,32);
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> {
    if (i < 5) return "a";
    else if (i < 25) return "b";
    return "c";
  }, Collectors.toList()));
```